# Abréviations et ponctuation en fin de phrase

Tags: typographie, abréviations, ponctuation

Quand l'expression « etc. » se trouve en fin de phrase le point provenant de l'abréviation et celui provenant de la ponctuation se confondent et l'on obtient la forme suivante :

> […], etc.

Dans le cas d'une phrase exclamative ou interrogative, les points n'étant pas aux mêmes endroits je ne sais pas si le même mécanisme s'applique.

> […], etc. !
>   […], etc. ?

ou

> […], etc !
>   […], etc ?

Quelles sont les formes correctes ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Les deux réponses en place sont effectivement correctes.

J'ai trouvé une source officielle¹, la Bande de dépannage linguistique du Québec, qui est un outil créé et maintenu par l'[Office québécois de la langue française](http://www.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/index.html).

[Et je cite :](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=3401)

> Si le mot abrégé termine la phrase, le point abréviatif se confond avec le point final ou bien, le cas échéant, avec les points de suspension. **Il n’annule cependant aucun autre signe de ponctuation.** Notons par ailleurs que le point abréviatif qui se trouve en milieu de phrase ne marque aucune pause et qu’il est suivi d’une minuscule.

(Le texte en gras vient de moi.)

La forme correcte pour un point interrogation ou un point d'exclamation est donc :

> […], etc. !

Mais si l'abréviation est suivie par des points de suspension ou un point, on doit le compter dans le nombre de points total. Je prends ici un autre exemple que *etc.* puisque celui-ci est redondant avec les points de suspension :

> […], app…

—
<sup>1. pour Romain VALERI</sup>

Answer (score 8):

**Le point du point d'exclamation ou d'interrogation ne remplacent pas celui de l'abréviation.**

Les formes correctes sont donc les premières

> J'étais submergé de goules, zombies, fantômes, etc. !

Comment: Réponse claire et satisfaisante mais un peu péremptoire. Des sources éventuelles ?

Comment: J'avoue ne pas avoir trouvé de source(s) officielle(s). Mais absolument toutes les sources (non officielles) que j'ai trouvé en faisant la recherche était du même avis. Je vais continuer à chercher une réponse claire et officielle pendant quelques jours et j'éditerai si je trouve.

Answer (score 0):

La forme correcte est effectivement la première :

> … etc. !

Selon [le projet voltaire](http://www.projet-voltaire.fr/blog/regle-orthographe/etc-ou-etc).

Note que cela n’est pas dit explicitement sur la page, mais que dans le test informatique on est mis face à des situations de ce type et la réponse est bien la première.

Enfin, oublier l’espace insécable juste avant cette abréviation est aussi une erreur typographique courante. À ne pas oublier, donc !